# Default template parameter with class

Tags: c++, templates, default-value

I've just found out about a strange syntax for default template parameters

```
template<class T = class Z>
struct X
  {};
```

What does the second "class" keyword mean in this context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's nothing special really. C++ allows you to refer to a class via an [elaborated type specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.elab#2). E.g.

```
void foo(class bar*);
```

This declares a function `foo` that accepts an argument of the type `bar*`. If `bar` was not declared previously, this elaborate type specifier constitutes a declaration of `bar` in the namespace containing `foo`. I.e. as if you had written:

```
class bar;
void foo(bar*);
```

Back to your example, `X` is a class template that expects a single type parameter, denoted by `class T`, but could have been denoted just the same as `typename T`. Said type parameter has a default argument, named by the elaborated class specifier `class Z`. That declaration can be rewritten just like the function above:

```
class Z;
template<class T = Z>
struct X
  {};
```